# Remove percentage on DoughtChart in ng2 chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

[I need to create a chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ9cV.pngstrong)

I need to remove that percentage showing on bar in doughtchart

This is my code

```
 public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    showLines: false,
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
  };
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: this.randomize() }
  ];
  public doughnutChartColors2: Array<any> = [{
    backgroundColor: ['#58dfa7']

  }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chartjs you can disable the plugins (in this case the label plugin).

By adding this to options labels would be diabled:

```
plugins: {
  labels: false
}
```